# How to remove .html permalink without every post getting 404?

Tags: permalinks

While there are lots of posts about adding '.html' to your permalinks, I can't find anything about removing it.

I changed permalinks from how the previous volunteer set it up (/%category%/%postname%.html) to remove '.html' (/%category%/%postname%/), but now posts are all getting 404 errors.

What's the right way to do this if I want to remove all the '.html' extensions without the errors?

Would the [redirection plugin](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/) be causing the problem?

Comment: Which permalink is showing a 404 **after** you changed settings? `/category/postname.html` or `/category/postname/`

Comment: Currently what output you are getting ?

Comment: fastest method is to add a redirect via .htaccess and not involve WordPress at all.